# Private User Messenging System

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

*This may not be specific to DA meta as to a possible site wide suggestion to SE. If it is side wide to SE then forgive me for asking here. Also, if this has been suggested before and rejected then disregard the question and remove it.*

**Is it possible to create a messaging system between users other than the chatrooms?**

I've had several instances were I would have liked to send a message to a user but have only been able to speak to them via comments on questions. Now I can see the purpose of NOT having the messaging system private as to keep the site engaged in the Q&A format but I think it would make an amazing addition to the stack exchange system. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user), and it has been rejected.
It has been also asked when [Stack Overflow used Uservoice](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/forums/1722-general/suggestions/14640-messaging-between-users) ([twice](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/forums/1722-general/suggestions/14640-messaging-between-users), [three times](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/forums/1722-general/suggestions/99462-allow-private-messages), and [four times](https://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/forums/1722-general/suggestions/216825-how-do-you-send-a-message-to-a-stackoverflow-user-)), and the feature request was declined.

The rejection reason is that Stack Exchange is not a social network; it's a Q&A platform.
If users need a way to exchange comments about a post, that is done with comments; for any other uses, there are chat rooms.